# url with: "/servlet" goes to "ip/servlet" instead of "ip/app/servlet"

Tags: java, url, ubuntu, tomcat7

I have for the first time tried an ubuntu server with tomcat7 instead of a windows server.

For java web projects when I was calling servlets or just making link, I would make code the url like "/servlet" and it would go to ip/app/servlet, but instead here on ubuntu ip/servlet (like it is the name of the webapp). If I remove the forward slash it works, but thats really inconvenient, since when I develop and test on my mac, it works fine with forward slash.

I had changed tomcat7 to listen on port 80 instead of 8080, but not sure if this has anything to do with it?

It also makes me wonder if I have left any security holes open?

Anyone know how this should be resolved?

note: this is not only an issue for servlets but jsps, htmls etc.

Comment: Tell us what the URL of the page that contains that link is in the address bar, and show us how you generate this URL in the source code of your page. Also, what is `ip`? Is it the context path of your webapp?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, `ip` is just the servers ip address. Calling `request.getContextPath` on the index file just returns `/appname`. I just code the link with a normal html a tag `<a href="/user.jsp">Go to user</a>`. This example will go to `ipaddress/user.jsp` instead of `ipadress/appname/user.jsp`

Comment: I think I found the problem to be that I have had the luxury of working behind an apache server that did some proxy things (not really to keen on what it does), which had the benefit of me not having to add the contextpath in front of URLs before. Is there anyway I can tomcat do the same work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want URLs like /user.jsp to point to your app in Tomcat, then you'll have to deploy your app as the root application (by naming it ROOT.war)

If you want to make things properly, then don't assume anything about the context path, and alwas prepend it to all the URLs in the application. This is easily done by using the `<c:url>` tag of the JSTL:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/user.jsp'/>">
```

This tag is also extremaly useful to properly encode parameters in URLs, and you should use it anyway.